# python operation by category and populating a dictionary from file

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following data

```
#RefName    Pos Coverage
chromosome_1    0   26
chromosome_1    1   0
chromosome_1    2   0
chromosome_1    3   0
chromosome_1    4   7
chromosome_1    5   0
chromosome_1    6   0
chromosome_1    7   2
chromosome_1    8   0
chromosome_35   33  0
chromosome_35   34  0
chromosome_35   35  0
chromosome_35   36  0
chromosome_35   37  0
chromosome_35   38  0
chromosome_35   39  8
chromosome_35   40  0
chromosome_35   41  0
chromosome_35   42  0
```

I want to have a dictionary, the key would be the first column, and the value a list of Pos, when Coverage > 4 I am almost there but my problem is to have the code start all over again for each new chromosome

```
    my_dict= {}
    my_list= []
    with open ("test.startStop.pileup", "r") as pileup:
        for line in pileup:
            if not line.startswith('#'):
                line = line.rstrip()
                fields = line.split('\t')
                if int(fields[2]) > 4:                
                    my_list.append(int(fields[1]))
                    my_dict[fields[0]] = my_list
for key,val in my_dict.items():
    print (key, "=>", val)
```

the list my_list should be created anew for each chromosome. 
the expected output is

```
chromosome_1 => [0, 4]
chromosome_35 => [39]
```

but of course I get

```
chromosome_1 => [0, 4, 39]
chromosome_35 => [0, 4, 39]
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks !

EDIT: I think I found how to gather my keys

```
my_dict= {}
my_list= []
with open ("test.startStop.pileup", "r") as pileup:
    for line in pileup:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            line = line.rstrip()
            fields = line.split('\t')
            my_dict[fields[0]] = None
```

But now I should reread the file from start. 
I was thinking of something of the sort:

```
for key in my_dict:
                my_list = []
                if key == fields[0] and int(fields[2]) > 4:  
                    my_list.append(int(fields[1]))  
            my_dict[key] = my_list
```

but where should I put that block? should I reopen the for reading again?

Comment: in your expected output should chromosome_35 s list be `[39]` I dont understand why it would be 8

Comment: Indeed, just a typo, sorry, it's corrected to be 39.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used re.split just cause my IDE was not nice with pasting the data but the below should show you what you need to do in your code. Essentially if the coverage is greater then 4 then check if the ref is already in the dict. if its not then create the ref whith an empty list as its val in the dict. Then append the pos to the list val of the ref in the dict. This way you will always append to the list if coveragee is greater than 4 and only create a new ref and list if this ref has never been seen

```py
data = """#RefName    Pos Coverage
chromosome_1    0   26
chromosome_1    1   0
chromosome_1    2   0
chromosome_1    3   0
chromosome_1    4   7
chromosome_1    5   0
chromosome_1    6   0
chromosome_1    7   2
chromosome_1    8   0
chromosome_35   33  0
chromosome_35   34  0
chromosome_35   35  0
chromosome_35   36  0
chromosome_35   37  0
chromosome_35   38  0
chromosome_35   39  8
chromosome_35   40  0
chromosome_35   41  0
chromosome_35   42  0"""

import re
data_dict = {}
for line in data.splitlines()[1:]:
    ref, pos, coverage = re.split(r"\s+", line.rstrip())
    if int(coverage) > 4:
        if ref not in data_dict:
            data_dict[ref] = []
        data_dict[ref].append(pos)
print(data_dict)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'chromosome_1': ['0', '4'], 'chromosome_35': ['39']}
```